# Drawing transparent bitmap on panel

Tags: c++, bitmap, wxwidgets

I want to draw a rectangle with rounded corners on a **wxPanel**.
As shown below, i am unable to get it transparent. The white area should be transparent.

[image]
The grey area is a **bitmap** and below it there is a **wxPanel** background.
My code for drawing bitmap (**wxBitmap**) is

```
wxMemoryDC temp;
bitmap.Create(kWidth, kHeight);
temp.SelectObject(bitmap);
temp.SetBackground(*wxWHITE_BRUSH);
temp.Clear();
temp.SetPen(wxPen(wxColor(80, 80, 80), 1));
temp.SetBrush(*wxTRANSPARENT_BRUSH);
temp.DrawRectangle(0, 0, kWidth, kHeight);
temp.SetBrush(wxBrush(backgroundColor));
temp.DrawRoundedRectangle(0, 0, kWidth, kHeight, kRadius);
```

And for bliting (for refresh) my code is

```
void draw(wxDC& dc, wxPoint mousePosition)
{
    wxMemoryDC temp;
    temp.SelectObject(bitmap);
    dc.Blit(wxPoint(kLeft, kTop), temp.GetSize(), &temp, wxPoint(0, 0), wxCOPY, true);
}
```

But the output is as shown above.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The pixel format of the bitmap matters, you don't specify the *depth* argument in the bitmap constructor.  32bpp required so alpha works, wxWidgets has limited support for it.  For Windows you'll need, say, gdiplus.

Comment: i don't exactly require alpha. isn't it possible in 24bits. just one color to be transparent?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145141%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: @HansPassant : i am using wxWidgets, the link seems not much help!

Comment: Isn't temp.SetBackground(*wxWHITE_BRUSH); setting the bitmap to solid white? Does temp.SetBackground(*wxTRANSPARENT_BRUSH); work?

Comment: @Brad: No `temp.SetBackground(*wxTRANSPARENT_BRUSH);` doesn't work! I have discovered that `wxDC` is incapable of handling transparency.

Answer (score 0):

Draw the same rounded rectangle in a wxMask. Make the corners you want to see through black and the parts you want visible white. Then call bitmap.SetMask with your wxMask object. With the mask applied to your wxBitmap it should blt properly in your Draw method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see that yellow background of your parent's control instaed of white background under rounded corners, you'll need to create the shaped control. Under Windows this can be achievend by using WinAPI's [SetWindowRgn()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.
Your wxPanel is not transparent. It has some background color even if you are drawing on it with transparent brush so you will anyway see the opaque area under rounded corners if you don't create the shaped control.
For other platforms there should be also some native implementation (no default wxWidgets API exists for this I think). For Linux and wxGTK you can obtain GdkWindow * by using [GetHandle()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html#a185e6cd7065367b552748cb722651b27) method of wxWindow and create the rounded control's shape using GDK pixmap I think.

The other way is obtaining the piece of parent's background under your wxPanel, drawing it on your panel, then drawing the rounded rectangle.